# Forward and Backward Euler

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I want to analytically solve

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = −αy,$$ where initial conditions are $y=1$ at $t=0$

and show the forward Euler method gets a smaller answer than the backward Euler method  $\forall$ $t>0$, provided that $0$ <$\alpha^2$ $\Delta t^2$ < $1$

Any help whatsoever will be appreciated!

Comment: What part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 2):

At the core you have to show that for $|x|<1$
$$
1+x\le e^x\le\frac1{1-x}.
$$